# Parsing XML with JQuery general help...no code included in question

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am new to parsing XML and I am trying to learn. I chose the xml feed here:

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml

To begin learning to parse with. All I want to do right now is write some simple variable values from it. Anyone have a good guide for this? Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for all the help.. anyone know how I could simply write out the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery knows how to interpret XML. When you do an AJAX call you can tell it to get the response in XML format. You can then read the response similar to the way you'd read the DOM.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // Interpret response
        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {

            // Example: Show the XML tag in the console
            console.log(this);

            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("hnn"));

        });
    }
});
```

Credit to http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: To print out the "hnn" attribute, for example, create a DIV in your HTML with the id "divOutput" and run $("#divOutput").append(this.attr("hnn")); in the inner-most loop. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the selector to get the node.

eg `$('gms')` will give you `"<gms w="1" y="2011" t="P" gd="0">` as a jQuery selector

and then the `attr()` function to get the attributes

eg `$('g:first').attr('hnn') would give you`patriots`